# google sheet custom menu function not visible in google sheet on android

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created in google sheets a custom menu linked to a custom function that pops up a dialog window with a youtube video in it. All this i did on my PC in a browser.

I now installed google sheets on my android phone, and shared the sheet myself (using a second gmail account). I now notice that the custom menu doesn't appear in google sheets app on android.

I am wondering, does custom menus and dialogs work in google sheets on android. Am i doing something incorrect in relation to permissions -- i.e. are there any permissions i need to assign to other users for them to see and use custom menu items and related functions. If yes, how can i make the correct settings.

thank you,

Dan

Comment: Nope, your desktop menus will not appear in the Google Sheets android app. If you need to offer things to the mobile app, you'll have to write a mobile add-on: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/mobile/ Note the restrictions.

Comment: I need a way to have the user trigger the script that makes sense to the user. One way i tried was to include a clickable image. But also, this doesn't work on the mobile google sheet app.

Comment: @tehhowch that link doesn't seem to work anymore. I can't find the article you are referencing. If you can provide an update, that would be awesome.

Comment: @AtiqZabinski you'll want to implement a "Google Workspace add-on" https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types?hl=en#add-ons as the regular "editor add-on" are not able to function on mobile client applications

Answer (score 7):

i used a drop-down list/combo - populated using data validation.  this is supported on mobile device.  then i use the onEdit(e) event to trigger the code... the first step is to identify what's been edited (which cell) and then act accordingly... an example follows where the drop-down would contain two items "Do Task 1" and "Do Task 2"... the event is triggered when any cell on the sheet is changed... the process then identifies if the cell change is that of the drop-down (cell value set to a global variable 'FunctionsCell')  if it is the drop-down that triggered the event, it then gets the value (see the 'getValue()' part of the code) and then inspects it's value and then executes the code accordingly (see '// do something part')

```
var FunctionsCell = "B2"  // global

function onEdit(e) {

var editCell = e.range.getA1Notation()

switch (editCell) {
case FunctionsCell:
  {               
      var functionType = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(FunctionsCell).getValue()

      switch(functionType) {              
        case "Do Task 1": {
          // do something
          break
        }
        case "Do Task 2": {
          // do something
          break
        }
      }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great outside the box solution. Thank you Ronnie

Comment: @Ronnie C Data validation menus do not allow for submenus and separators as Custom Menus do.